# Catch negative numbers with regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm using the following regex to catch numbers with dots and commas, somethings the two together -> `/^\d+([,.]\d+)*$/`

See here: https://regex101.com/r/hJ3lV9/1

I would like to catch the negative versions two: like:

```
-10
-10.50,50
-10,50.50
-10.50
```

Is it possible?

Thanks.

Comment: In your example it looks like you have comma separated values, and dot is used as decimal separator. Or the other way around. I think the regex shouldn't accept both as decimal separator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this you mean:

```
/^-?\d+([,.]\d+)*$/
```

Where `-?` accepts dash as an optional character

Comment: No need to put the hyphen into a character class. It is not a special character outside of a character class. At least in JS regex.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew understood it is just a personal preference for syntax

Comment: No, it is an ambiguity that one should not introduce into one's regex patterns: do not use a construct if one does not have to.

Comment: I haven't read the book that says so, I guess is another preference because it does not affect performance, so I do not see the harm in doing so. Not that I am saying I am right, I may not be

Comment: Yes, you can put `a` into `[a]`, and `b` into `[b]` etc. Just some users will think you can put *sequences* into `[...]` - and that will be a problem then. You do not have to read any book - it is suffice to see what people ask for here on SO.

Comment: On that I agree... "for sake of simplicity and avoiding misunderstandings is better not too"

Comment: Here is the same answer (with some extra grouping to make extracting the value easier): `^(-?\d+(?:[,.]\d+)*)$` https://regex101.com/r/hJ3lV9/3